# Remotely execute an exe file from network shared drive?

Tags: windows, networking

So I manage an office with about 150 computers.
I need to run a exe file on each of these machines.

I have placed my file to run on the network sharing drive but to run the file I will have to individually go to each computer and execute it.
I was wondering if it is possible to remotely execute the exe file on all machines in the network, (the machines are named in numbers such as xyzcompany1, xyzcompany2....).

Is it possible?

Comment: try super user...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into using PsExec?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

My apologies for being vague with the answer the first time.

I would assume since the file is in a network shared folder you would first have to copy the file to the applicable workstation and then execute the program once copied.

To Copy Remote File:

```
psexec \\workstation123 -s cmd /c copy \\server21\share45\file.exe c:\localpath
```

Then Run It:

```
psexec \\workstation123 "c:\localpath\file.exe"
```

Comment: @DanielMann - Sorry about that, you're right. Edited. :)